# Ingress with client certificate authentication

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, ssl-client-authentication

I have a service that needs to be protected by client certification. I have this configuration for my ingress resource

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "namespace/ca-chain"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
```

And i get the `ssl-client-verify` header with a value of `SUCCESS` delivered to my backend. If this is set, i know that the client certificate was validated correctly.

Is this the correct setup? Doesn't this setup rely on the fact, that my backend is closely coupled with my ingress, and if the ingress goes away, a bad actor can just send a request, with a `ssl-client-verify` header set to `SUCCESS` and we let him in.

Two questions comes in mind:

1. with a standard ingress setup in k8s, all requests always goes through the ingress, and no requests can go around the ingress? From what i can read, all traffic always go through the ingress: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress
2. should i validate the chain myself? I get the client certificate delivered in the header? I have only one client, so i actually don't need to do further authentification: if they have valid client certificate, i can let them in

If this is the right pattern, doesn't this mean that we, always need something infront of our app, if we descide to move it out of k8s? Fx if i want to run it on a stand alone server: then i need a nginx in front, with the same configuration, so it can handle client certification for me, or else a bad actor can just call around my nginx and set the `ssl-client-verify` header to `SUCCESS` and we think all is a-okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with a standard ingress setup in k8s, all requests always goes through the ingress, and no requests can go around the ingress?

That's correct. A pod runs in an isolated network namespace. Without additional configuration, there's no way to reach it externally. If the ingress service goes down, there's no "going around" it.

> should i validate the chain myself?

You can't. Only the service performing SSL termination can perform the certificate validation. Your nginx ingress is handling the SSL connection, so that's where validation happens.

If you want to handle SSL termination yourself, you would probably need to set up a LoadBalancer type service...but I don't think that would really get you much other than increased complexity.

> If this is the right pattern, doesn't this mean that we, always need something infront of our app, if we descide to move it out of k8s?

If you're handling authentication with a front-end proxy in Kubernetes...then you would also need to handle authentication with a front-end proxy outside of Kubernetes. That's a common pattern. If you want to write your application so that it can work with or without a frontend proxy, then you would need to add configuration options to enable/disable that behavior.

Comment: I sounds like if I keep it behind an ingress of some sort it is s fine pattern to do client cert validation, so the service behind it doesn't need to worry about it. If we move it outside, we need lock it down behind an ingress as well.